# Scan QR Codes on Windows 10 IoT (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: qr-code, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, windowsiot

Does anyone knows how to scan QR codes on Windows 10 IoT for Raspberry Pi? I was able to install a camera, and make it work but I can't find any component that supports QR scanner. Anyone with such experience?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Diego just wondering what camera you used and how you got it working?

Could you use https://zxingnet.codeplex.com?

Comment: I'm using the RasPi camera, the one you plug to the special connector in the board.